# Pass value from button in HTML to function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm trying to pass some value from button, which is located in HTML document, to the Javascript function, which is located in other document, but it doesn't work. I also tried with getElementById(), but it still didn't work. What's the problem? I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

index.html

```
<script src="../scripts/appearances_2.js"></script>
/...
<div id="appearances_2_chart">
        <div>
           <button id="starting" onclick="update_view('starting')">Starting players</button>
           <button id="substitution" onclick="update_view('substitution')">Substitution players</button>
        </div>
</div>
/...
```

appearances_2.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
//...
function update_view(id) {

      d3.csv("../../data/appearances.csv", function(data) {

        data.sort(function(b, a) {
            if (id == 'starting')
            {
              return a.starting - b.starting;
            }
            else if (id == 'substitution')
            {
              return a.substitution - b.substitution;
            }
        });
/...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use, event as an object to be passed and access the value as (in order to get the id),

`event.target.getAttribute('id')`

You need to modify the button code as,

`<button id="starting" onclick="update_view(event)">Starting players</button>`

and in function,

`update_view(event){....}`

and access the id using the target object as mentioned in the first code.

Update:-

```js
function update_view(event) { 
  d3.csv("../../data/appearances.csv", function (data) { 
    data.sort(function (b, a) { 
      if (event.target.getAttribute('id') === 'starting') { 
        return a.starting - b.starting; 
      } 
      else if (event.target.getAttribute('id') === 'substitution') {
        return a.substitution - b.substitution; 
      } 
    })
  })
};
```

```html
<button id="starting" onclick="update_view(event)">Starting players</button> 
<button id="substitution" onclick="update_view(event)">Substitution players</button>
```

Comment: Where does e.target.getAttribute('id') go?

Comment: Inside the function where you want to access the value of id attribute, in this case inside update_view function

Comment: Let me know if you have any other issue!

Comment: One more thing use ‘===‘ to equate and also check once are you getting the proper attribute value or not ?

Comment: Since I am working in D3.js, my bar chart doesn't show.

Comment: There might be some other error, can you tell me is there anything showing up on console ?

Comment: `function update_view(e) {
    
      d3.csv("../../data/appearances.csv", function(data) {

        data.sort(function(b, a) {
            if (e.target.getAttribute('id') === 'starting')
            {
              return a.starting - b.starting;
            }
            else if (e.target.getAttribute('id') === 'substitution')
            {
              return a.substitution - b.substitution;
            }
        });`

Comment: <button id="starting" onclick="update_view(e)">Starting players</button>
<button id="substitution" onclick="update_view(e)">Substitution players</button>

Comment: Checking it, give me sometime

Comment: I have updated the answer, copy-paste the code from there, if your d3 is working, your code will work :)

Comment: If there is any other issue let me know then!